# Opening Aura framework

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

How to open aura framework/platform? Is it needed to download aura? Please point me if anyone knows any information.

Comment: Can you clarify...Aura refers to the open source project that is the foundational technology for Lightning Components. Lightning Component Framework is the implementation of Aura on the Force.com platform. Which is it you were interested in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following urls should get you started on Lightning components.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/lightning/lightning.pdf

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2014/10/14/tutorial-build-your-first-lightning-component/

Rudy